# Angular 2 table loads empty after adding a Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 2 and am developing a small application which has a form and a table.
The form is used to enter the filter criteria. Once user click on Submit button, data should be loaded to the table.  When loading first time, the grid should be filled with all the data from DB table.

I use following code in my home.component.html file.

```html
<div class='panel panel-primary'>

    <div class='panel-body'>

        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <!--<div style="padding-bottom:10px"><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addUser()">Add</button></div>-->
            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" *ngIf="indLoading"><img src="../../images/loading.gif" width="32" height="32" /> Loading...</div>
            <div *ngIf='warehouses && warehouses.length==0' class="alert alert-info" role="alert">No record found!</div>
            <table class='table table-striped' *ngIf='warehouses && warehouses.length'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Territory Code</th>
                        <th>Warehouse Code</th>
                        <!--<th>Gender</th>-->
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let warehouse of warehouses">
                        <td>{{warehouse.TerritoryCode}}</td>
                        <td>{{warehouse.WarehouseCode}}</td>

                        <!--<td>
                            <button title="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editUser(user.Id)">Edit</button>
                            <button title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(user.Id)">Delete</button>
                        </td>-->
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="msg" role="alert" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
            {{msg}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Data is loading with no issues as below.
[image]

However, when I add the form controls to home.component.html file using below code (paste this code at the top of home.component.html)

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Search</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value, myForm.valid)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Territory</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Territory">
            <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.Territory.valid || (myForm.controls.Territory.pristine && !submitted)" class="text-danger">
                Territory is required (minimum 5 characters).
            </small>
            <!--<pre class="margin-20">{{ myForm.controls.Territory.errors | json }}</pre>-->
        </div>
               
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The output is like below. It does not show the data in the table(When loading for the first time.). What could be the reason??[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `FormArray` here for your data, so your build of the form should look like this:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  warehouses: this.fb.array([])
})
```

I like to fill the form after getting the data from the backend, that is what I assume you are getting your data from, so in the callback (subscribe) call `setWarehouses`, which looks like this, where we iterate the warehouses you have received, and for each object create a form group with the two properties.

```
setWarehouses(){
  let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.warehouses;
  this.warehouses.forEach(x => {
    control.push(this.fb.group({territoryCode: x.TerritoryCode, warehouseCode: x.WarehouseCode}))
  })
}
```

Then your template should look like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <!-- the formarray -->
  <table formArrayName="warehouses">
    <tr>
      <th>Territory Code</th>
      <th>Warehouse Code</th>
    </tr>
   <!-- Iterate the formGroups in the form array -->
   <tr *ngFor="let warehouse of myForm.controls.warehouses.controls; let i=index">
    <!-- Each form group has a index -->
    <ng-container formGroupName="{{i}}">
      <!-- The form controls -->
      <td><input formControlName="territoryCode" /></td>
      <td><input formControlName="warehouseCode" /></td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/0074yDXtHdAoet32forh?p=preview)**

Comment: I will try implementing this way. Thanks.

Comment: @ChathurangaRanasinghe Sure, let me know how it goes! :)